# H bridge with a single I/O control and NPN at the top

Tags: bjt, h-bridge, npn, pnp

I want to control a 4V motor to rotate both directions which draws 100mA and I was looking at the [H-bridge schematics](https://www.build-electronic-circuits.com/h-bridge/). The tutorial says that you should place NPN transistors at the bottom if you need >5V Power to the motor, which i dont need. This H-bridge also requires at least two inputs to switch direction. I also do not need to turn the motor off. It will run either or one direction, or the other.

I was wondering if I could put the NPN transistor at the top, so that I can control the motor with only one I/O pin (simplified schematic):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFI5cE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since I don't need >5V power for the motor, I don't need to put my NPN transistors at the bottom.
Using this schematic I can also control the direction of the motor with only one I/O, without more external components.

Of course, the complete schematic will also include a resistor to limit the Base current and the fly back diodes (fly back diodes and Base resistor added):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flueOU.png)</sup>

When I/O is 5V, both NPN transistors turn on.

When I/O is 0V, both PNP transistors turn on.

Do you think this will work? I have not seen any tutorial/schematic with this H-bridge configuration.

Comment: This can easily be simulated in LTSpice. Or any of the additional free simulators. I do wonder if your MCU will be able to drive two transistors into saturation though.  Simulation and datasheet inspection can answer that though.

Comment: Hm you are right! i should start using that LTSpice.

Comment: no good.  the common emitter pair on the right side turn each other on.

Comment: @PeteW Right, the right side pair is just 2 diode junctions right across the supply, and the left side pair are emitter followers which can only pull down to a diode drop above ground or up to the base drive voltage minus a diode drop.  The left side of the bridge could kind of work if the power dissipation in the transistors is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Aaron stated, I should simulate this in LTspice.